# Nginx: Redirect .php requests to extension-less version

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I have the following configuration that now rewrites `/create_user/check` to `/create_user.php?check=true`.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ext-php;
}

location @ext-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)/create_user/check$ $1/create_user.php?check=true last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Additionally, I want to redirect users using the "create_user.php?check=true" version to the extension-less version. What is the best way to configure that?

Is a rewrite in the server block (as follows) a good way to do this?

```
rewrite ^(.*)/create_user.php?check=true$ $1/create_user/check redirect;
```

**Update:** The following configuration changes work:
Added a map block:

```
map $query_string $updated_path {
    "check=true" "check"; }
```

and changed the rewrite in the server block to:

```
 rewrite ^(.*/create_user).php$ $1/$updated_path? redirect;
```

Comment: I have found that the rewrite rules can't use GET parameters in its rule. From what I understand now, if statements that check the $request_uri is needed.

Comment: Please don't add multiple comments after you ask a question, edit your question to provide all the information and delete the comments. The config you added to the comment is close to unreadable without formatting.

Comment: Please add your own solution as an answer to the question, do not add it to the question itself.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: The purpose of the question was to understand the best (or at least the recommended) way of achieving this. I have seen many websites use extensionless urls, and redirecting the version with extensions to them. Because I have an experience of only a few hours in Nginx configuration, I can't be certain that this is the **best** solution. I feel that it is unfortunate that there are more comments about etiquette than the actual issue being discussed.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I read the question too quickly, and missed the "best way" part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this would be like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

location ~ ^(.*)/create_user/check$ {
    rewrite ^ $1/create_user.php?check=true last;
}

location ~ ^(.*)/create_user.php$ {
    if ($arg_check = "true") {
        return 302 $1/create_user/check;
    }
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

In general, it is best to use `location` blocks for matching different URLs and then perform operations you want in them.

I changed your original rewrite directive to the first `location` block in my answer. We capture the first part of the URI into `$1` variable. (Do you really need to match any path before `create_user` part here?).

Then, in the other `location` block we match the `create_user` URL. Then we check if the query argument `check` contains the string true, if it does, we send a 302 redirect to the user.

I don't think it is possible to avoid using `if` here. However, I still think this is a more efficient approach.

The main difference here is that we don't run the `rewrite` directive for every missing file.

However, as a last point. I recommend implementing front-controller pattern in your application, so that all requests are sent to `index.php`, which then takes care of parsing the URLs.

There is a limit how much one can do in nginx side, and when you reach that limit, you have to rebuild things anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the comment above. I was a little upset about not getting any answers at all. :)